# Singular Jacobian in Boundary Value Problem

Tags: python, numpy, ode, differential-equations, boundary

I am solving a set of coupled ODEs using `solve_bvp` in python. I have solved the equations for the boundary conditions that U = 0 and B = 0 on the boundaries, however I am trying to solve them such that U' = 0 and B = 0 on the boundary. My problem is that I keep encountering a singular jacobian in the return message - my guess is that the initial guess is diverging, however I have tried a range of initial guesses and still no solution. Is there a more systematic way of figuring this out? My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 1000)
y = np.ones((4, x.size))
y[0] = U_0*np.tanh(Q*x)
U_0 = 0.1
Q = 30

## Then we calculate the total energy

def FullSolver(x,y,Ha, Rm):

    def fun(x, y):

        U, dU, B, dB = y;
        d2U = -2*U_0*Q**2*(1/np.cosh(Q*x))**2*np.tanh(Q*x)-((Ha**2)/(Rm))*dB;   
        d2B = -Rm*dU;

        return dU, d2U, dB, d2B
    def bc(ya, yb):

        return ya[1], yb[1], ya[2]-0, yb[2]+0    
    # sol will give us the solutions which are accessible if we need them
    sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y, tol=1e-12)
    return(sol.x, sol.yp[0], sol.y[2], sol.message)
FullSolver(x, y, 0.000005, 0.00009)
```

Comment: `solve_bvp` is experimental code, not production robust. You might get a better result with a one-shot approach using a numerical solver like `scipy.optimize.fsolve`. Most likely your initial guess is too far away from a solution and the solver iteration diverges to large values.

Comment: How do I use that to solve differential equations? I can write my equations of the form func(x) = 0, but it is not clear to me how that would solve for the functions.

Comment: You define a shooting function `def shoot(x): U0,dB0 = x; U1, dU1, B1, dB1 = odeint(func,[U0,0,0,dB0],[x0,xf],tfirst=True)[-1]; return [ dU1, B1]` and pass that to the non-linear solver. Adapt tolerances and max. step size as desired. Doing that with `solve_ivp` has one or two commands more due to the return type format.

Comment: I think that makes a little more sense --- however, I am trying to contrast it with the following problem solution https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/02/15/Plane-Poiseuille-flow-BVP-solve-by-shooting-method/ 
However, it is unclear how to implement the differential boundary conditions rather than the standard conditions.

Comment: The problem is that the right sides do not depend on U or B, so that if they are not bound by the boundary values like in your case, then with any solution `U` also `U+C` is a solution for any constant `C`. This means that the system is under-determined and thus you get a singular Jacobian.

Comment: The problem is that the right sides do not depend on U or B, so that if they are not bound by the boundary values like in your case, then with any solution `U` also `U+C` is a solution for any constant `C`. This means that the system is under-determined and thus you get a singular Jacobian.

Comment: That makes sense, I did notice that when I integrated one equation up and substituted it into the other. What is the best way around solving something like that? Is there any hope to solve the equations numerically with those boundary conditions?